How can I fix this pipeline?
I have searched EOTP error but this is in github action, I cannot input the 2FA code. Moreover,
I cannot see the log and have no idea what has happened.
name: art-component-release
on:
 push:
   branches:
     - "main" # change to the branch you wish to deploy from

permissions:
 contents: read
 pages: write
 id-token: write

jobs:
 deploy:
   environment:
     name: github-pages
     url: ${{ steps.build-publish.outputs.page_url }}
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   steps:
     - id: build-publish
       uses: bitovi/github-actions-storybook-to-github-pages@v1.0.3
       with:
         path: storybook-static # change to your build folder
         build_command: npm run build-storybook

 publish:
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   steps:
     - name: Checkout code
       uses: actions/checkout@v4
     - name: Set up Node.js
       uses: actions/setup-node@v4
       with:
         node-version: 22.2.0
     - name: Install dependencies
       run: |
         npm ci
         npm run build
     - name: Add Npm Token # add access token to .npmrc
       run: |
         echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}" >> ./.npmrc
         ls -al
         cat ./.npmrc
     - name: Publish to npm # publish to npm registry
       run: npm publish
       env:
         GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ART }}
         NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}


error info is here.
npm error code EOTP
npm error This operation requires a one-time password from your authenticator.
npm error You can provide a one-time password by passing --otp=<code> to the command you ran.
npm error If you already provided a one-time password then it is likely that you either typoed
npm error it, or it timed out. Please try again.


Here is the action link.
https://github.com/S-N-O-R-L-A-X/art-components/actions/runs/10548056056/job/29221494477

The easiest solution to this issue is to replace NPM_TOKEN which is currently a personal Publish token with a new npm automation token.

this answer is the best solution but if security is not that of a priority just disale 2FA for the time being and test. or else create NPM_TOKEN

wow, it works! Thank you!

It is best to use a dedicated automation token to decouple from personal tokens. This is because you may have to revoke personal tokens and you do not want to break you CI pipelines in the process.
